# Приложение для Chrome

Tags: javascript

Я делаю бота который удаляет лишние сообщения в Gmail.

Галочку для выбора всех писем я сумел нажать так:

```
$(".T-Jo-auh:first").click();
```

А вот кнопку "удалить" нажать програмно не могу. Пробовал сначала наводить потом нажимать но нечего не получилось:

```
        $(".T-I.J-J5-Ji.nX.T-I-ax7.T-I-Js-Gs.ar7").dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));
        $(".T-I.J-J5-Ji.nX.T-I-ax7.T-I-Js-Gs.ar7.T-I-JW").click();
```

Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему.

Comment: А просто вызвать то действие которое у них происходит при нажатии на кнопку ? Разумеется внедрив свой код в страницу, что бы он получил доступ к JS самой страницы

Comment: Лучше буду держаться подальше от таких расширений.

Comment: "Вызвать то действие которое у них происходит." 
Тут пожалуйста поподробней. Как вызвать?

Comment: Когда у вас 6к писем, скорее всего вам понадобиться такое приложение, чтобы удалить их автоматически.